# Opening a new window with 5 different tabs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, new-window

For an internal website, I need my users to click on a link, and that should open a new window with 5 new tabs on it.

I've managed to open 5 new windows, or 5 new tabs on the same window where they click, but not 1 window with 5 new tabs

My website is ruby on rails but I'm guessing it'll all be javascript

I can force my users to use a specific browser, that's not an issue

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, calling `window.open()` from JS will open either a new window *or* a new tab, depending on the user's browser settings. You cannot control which one.

Comment: Any ideas? Rethink whatever you are doing. There is no good reason you should be opening 5 tabs and doing so will just trigger the popup blocker in the browser.

Comment: It's for an internal use. We do online tours, and need to open 5 360 photos from google at the same time so they load and we can switch between them while we show people around. My users can allow popups, it is in their interest hehe

Comment: Still, just open one window with a carousel on it instead.

Comment: Each image is 360, and hosted on google maps, so I need to be able to move within the image! I don't see how I could do this with a carousel. Might be wrong, any pointers?